# How do I get last modified date from a Hadoop Sequence File?

Tags: java, date, hadoop, mapreduce

I am using a mapper that converts BinaryFiles (jpegs) to a Hadoop Sequence File (HSF):

```
    public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) 
throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    String uri = value.toString().replace(" ", "%20");
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();

    FSDataInputStream in = null;
    try {
        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(URI.create(uri), conf);
        in = fs.open(new Path(uri));
        java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream bout = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte buffer[] = new byte[1024 * 1024];

        while( in.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length) >= 0 ) {
            bout.write(buffer);
        }
        context.write(value, new BytesWritable(bout.toByteArray()));
```

I then have a second mapper that reads the HSF, thus:

```
public  class ImagePHashMapper extends Mapper<Text, BytesWritable, Text, Text>{

    public void map(Text key, BytesWritable value, Context context) throws IOException,InterruptedException {
        //get the PHash for this specific file
        String PHashStr;
        try {
            PHashStr = calculatePhash(value.getBytes());
```

and calculatePhash is:

```
        static String calculatePhash(byte[] imageData) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        //get the PHash for this specific data
        //PHash requires inputstream rather than byte array
        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageData);
        String ph;
        try {
            ImagePHash ih = new ImagePHash();
            ph = ih.getHash(is);
            System.out.println ("file: " + is.toString() + " phash: " +ph);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "Internal error with ImagePHash.getHash";
        } 

        return ph;
```

This all works fine, but I want calculatePhash to write out each jpeg's last modified date. I know I can use `file.lastModified()` to get the last modified date in a file but is there any way to get this in either map or calculatePhash? I'm a noob at Java. TIA!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hi i think that you want is the modification time of each input File that enters in your mapper. If it is the case you just have to add a few lines to the mpkorstanje solution:

```java
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(URI.create(uri), conf);
long moddificationTime = fs
    .getFileStatus((FileSplit)context.getInputSplit())
    .getPath()).lastModified();
```

With this few changes you can get the fileStatus of each inputSlipt and you can add it to your key in order to use later in your process or make a multipleOutput reduce and write somewhere else in your reduce phase.

I hope this will be usefull

Comment: Add it to the key! So obvious now. Thanks!!

Comment: I could use the `.lastModified` method, instead I got the error `<console>:50: error: value lastModified is not a member of org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileStatus
               fs.getFileStatus(new Path(f)).lastModified()` Is it only available in certain versions of  `org.apache.hadoop.fs`?

Answer (score 5):

Haven't used Hadoop much but I don't think you should use `file.lastModified()`. Hadoop abstracted the file system somewhat.

Have you tried using [FileSystem.getFileStatus(path)](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.2.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html#getFileStatus(org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path)) in `map`? It gets you a [FileStatus](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.2.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileStatus.html) object that has a modification time. Something like

```
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(URI.create(uri), conf);
long moddificationTime = fs.getFileStatus(new Path(uri)).lastModified();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code snippet to get Map of all the files modified under particular directory path you provide:

```
private static HashMap lastModifiedFileList(FileSystem fs, Path rootDir) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    HashMap modifiedList = new HashMap();
    try {

        FileStatus[] status = fs.listStatus(rootDir);
        for (FileStatus file : status) {
            modifiedList.put(file.getPath(), file.getModificationTime());
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return modifiedList;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Hadoop each files are consist of BLOCK. 
Generally Hadoop FileSystem are referred the package **org.apache.hadoop.fs**.
If your input files are present in **HDFS** means you need to import the above package

```
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(URI.create(uri), conf);
in = fs.open(new Path(uri));

org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileStatus fileStatus=fs.getFileStatus(new Path(uri));
long modificationDate = fileStatus.getModificationTime();

Date date=new Date(modificationDate);
SimpleDateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss");
String dateText = df2.format(date);
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: What's difference between the above answers and yours? It seems both are same.